# How to call AnimateWindow function to animate a external window/process

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using the [ShowWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) function to hide and show the main window of a external process. Now, I would like to use the [AnimateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669(v=vs.85).aspx) function before calling **ShowWindow** to animate that window when I show or hide it, however, as the documentation says on MSDN, the **Animatewindow** function will fail if the thread (on which I'm calling **Animatewindow**) does not own the window that I want to animate...

Is there any solution for this?, I can "own" the thread in some way to remotely execute the **Animatewindow** function on the UI thread of that external process, or any other simpler solution to do this?. At least I know the window handle, and I can retrieve the thread id of the thread that created that window with the [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

So, this can be done in any way?.

If this info could be helpful: the external process is a .NET executable (a WPF desktop app), and I want to animate its main window. That application has support for plugins in form of dll files that the application wil load at startup, so I'm calling **ShowWindow** and **AnimateWindow** within a class library, running my code in a new thread on which I run a message-loop (for other needs). I don't have access to the source-code of that application to implement any kind of Inter-process communication features like named pipes or shared memory blocks.

I'm asking for a solution using C# or VB.NET, does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation says, only the thread that owns the window can call `AnimateWindow()` on the window.

You can't take ownership of someone else's threads or windows. So, the only way to accomplish your goal is to inject code into the thread that owns the window.

Have your plugin DLL call `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to get the ID of the thread that owns the window, and then call `SetWindowsHookEx()` to install a thread-specific message hook for that thread.

Then, you can send a custom message to the window, and your message hook handler will run in the context of the thread that owns the window, and can then call `AnimateWindow()` on the window.